# getting invoking module's name in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a more straight-forward way of getting the name of the invoking module than this:

```
script_file_path = sys.argv[0]
top_module_name = None
for frame in reversed(inspect.stack()):
    if frame[1] == script_file_path:
        top_module_name = inspect.getmodule(frame[0]).__name__
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "invoking module"?

Comment: I'm guessing he means `if a.py imports b.py, and b.py imports c.py, what code do I put in c.py to make it print "I was imported by b"?'

Comment: The name of the module corresponding to the script used to invoke the the current python process (e.g. `__main__`, however, it's not always `__main__`; e.g. multiprocessing).

Answer (score 0):

I think both of the following are certainly more efficient, and the first seems a bit more straightforward (at least, you deal with fewer indices, file paths, etc.). I think the first would work most of the time (but I have not tested it fully):

```
import inspect

def get_invoking_module():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    return frame.f_back.f_globals["__name__"]
```

This should work all the time:

```
def get_invoking_module():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    current_module = inspect.getmodule(frame)
    while inspect.getmodule(frame) == current_module:
        frame = frame.f_back                           # walk back up the frames
    if frame:
        return frame.f_globals["__name__"]
```